# How to use Taxonomy argument in Views 2 (Drupal 6)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I would like to display a view on a page with the URL syntax of:

www.sitename.com/what-we-do/TAXONOMY-NAME

The taxonomy name is seperated by dashes e.g. 'exhibition-design-management'. I want to only display nodes in the view which share the same taxonomy term from the url. How would I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Views 3 (D6 and D7), you'd add a taxonomy term field as an argument and then set it defaults to the term ID from URL. There is a check box to inherit current node's taxonomy term(s) that does what you want.

But this is not possible unless you manually load the term ID to the View. Try 
[Similar By terms](http://drupal.org/project/similarterms) module (which suits your use case I guess).
You can also check [this comparison table](http://drupal.org/node/323329) to determine which suits you best. You do not need any extra module for Views 3.